# WPF Twitter Integration

Tags: wpf, authentication, twitter

I've currently got an app that me and a few mates have be working on and we would like to add some degree of twitter integration - basically we would like a user to be able to logon and tweet from the application..

I've looked an API but they all seem to use MVC and some sort of Callback URLS to process the login..

My question is how exactly can we handle that with WPF? Ive really no idea so any help would be fantastic

The API we are using for the integration is http://www.twitterizer.net/..

**So - We are looking for how to manage the logon to Twitter through our application and how to store the Data safely.**

Comment: Have a look at Linq2Twitter - http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: So you're mostly concerned with authentication, authorization and managing user credentials? Do you have any existing code we could work with since it seems you're working with Twitterizer already?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes mate, that's exactly what we are looking for :) sadly nothing at the moment so it's a blank slate - ive just had a quick look at Linq2Twitter but I cant see how we do this in there documentation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

This is a good API which uses Linq.
You should try it out.

Comment: We are quite happy with the twitterizer API - they seem to have the fastest turn around with development against Twitter.. what we are looking for exactly is how to manage the login and integration against twitter, not just returning timelines or tweets.

Comment: After a second look - linq2Twitter looks perfect! thanks for the help!